# Sudoku game, serialization issue

Tags: java, serialization

I am creating the Sudoku game and I am trying to provide options to save, save as, and open games. I am using JFileChooser to do this. I am able to save (or "save as") but when I try to open a saved file, I get an error. I am new to programming and I'm hoping someone could spot the issue and educate me on how to read in the contents of the Sudoku board when I am saving (as well as how to deal with re-creating the Sudoku board when I open the file). I hear there is an easier way to deal with this using InputStream/OutputStream instead of Reader/Writer...

Here is my code for the inner class that implements this (I don't know if there's a way to post my entire class without exceeding the character limit for this text box.):

```
  // this inner class provides a JMenuBar object at the top of
  // the board
  class MenuAtTop extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener{

    // SudokuMain2 object we are dealing with
    private SudokuMain2 main;

    // the "File" menu
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    // the "New Game" option
    private JMenuItem newGame;
    // the "Open" option
    private JMenuItem open;
    // the "Save" option
    private JMenuItem save;
    // the "Save As" option
    private JMenuItem saveAs;
    // the "Reset" option
    private JMenuItem reset;
    // the "Quit" option
    private JMenuItem quit;

    // the ability to choose files
    private JFileChooser choose;

    // the saved file
//    // compiler would not allow "static" keyword
    private File fileSaved = null;

    private Object opener;

    // JDialog object to create a dialog box to prompt
    // user for new game information
    private JDialog createNewWin; 

    /**
     * Constructs MenuAtTop object.
     * 
     * @param m The SudokuMain2 object to be referred to.
     */
    public MenuAtTop(final SudokuMain2 m) {

      main = m;

      opener = null;
      choose = new JFileChooser();

      // instantiate and bind to reference
      fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
      add(fileMenu);

      // instantiate and bind to reference
      newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
      newGame.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,
                                                    ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(newGame);
      newGame.addActionListener(this);

      open = new JMenuItem("Open");
      open.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O,
                                                 ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(open);
      // add action listener to "Open" option
      open.addActionListener(this);

      save = new JMenuItem("Save");
      save.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,
                                                 ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(save);
//      //save.setEnabled(false);
      // add action listener to "Save" option
      save.addActionListener(this);

      saveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As");
      saveAs.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A,
                                                   ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(saveAs);
      // add action listener to "Save As" option
      saveAs.addActionListener(this);

      reset = new JMenuItem("Reset");
      reset.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R,
                                                  ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(reset);
      // add action listener to "Reset" option
      reset.addActionListener(this);

      quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
      quit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q,
                                                 ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(quit);
      // add action listener to "Quit" option
      quit.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if(e.getSource().equals(quit)) {
        closePrompt();
        //main.win.dispose();
      }
      else if(e.getSource().equals(reset)) {
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(main.win, 
                                              "Any player values will" +
                                              " be lost. Proceed?",
                                              "Warning!", 2);
        if(n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
          main.board.reset();

          main.view.repaint();
        }
      }
      else if(e.getSource().equals(saveAs)) {
        saveAs();
      }
      else if(e.getSource().equals(save)) {
        if(fileSaved == null) {
          saveAs();
        }
        else {
          try {
            board.writeToStream(new FileOutputStream(fileSaved));
//            main.board.setDirty(false);
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error saving file.");
          }
        }
      }

      else if(e.getSource().equals(open)) {

        int returnVal = choose.showOpenDialog(main.win);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          boolean error = false;
          File openFile = choose.getSelectedFile();

          try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(openFile);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            opener = ois.readObject();
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error opening file.");
            error = true;
          }

          if(opener != null && opener instanceof SudokuBase){
            main.west.remove(main.symbols);
            main.east.remove(main.view);
            //add in state information for new board
            main.south.remove(main.rowColRegStates);

            main.view =  new SudokuView((SudokuBase) opener);
            main.symbols = new SetSymbols(main.view);
            //add in state information for new board
            main.rowColRegStates = new ShowStates(main.view);

            main.west.add(main.symbols);
            main.east.add(main.view);
            //add in state information for new board
            main.south.add(main.rowColRegStates);

            main.win.requestFocus();

            fileSaved = openFile;
//            main.board.setDirty(false);
          } else {
            if(error) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, " Incorrect file type!");
            }
          }
        }
        // else: user cancelled
      }
      else if(e.getSource().equals(newGame)) {
        setEnabled(false);
        // create dialog box prompting for the new board information
        createNewWin = new Dialog1(main, "Create New Board", true);
        // make it visible
        createNewWin.setVisible(true);

        fileSaved = null;
      }
    }

    // This method prompts the user to choose a file to save to,
    // and then saves the file.
    private int saveAs() {
      boolean saveError;
      int rtn = choose.showSaveDialog(main.win);

      if(rtn == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        saveError = false;
        File fileSaveAs = choose.getSelectedFile();
        try {
          board.writeToStream(new FileOutputStream(fileSaveAs));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error saving file.");
          saveError = true;
        }

        if(!saveError) {
          fileSaved = fileSaveAs;
//          main.board.setDirty(false);
        }
      }

      return rtn;

    }

    /**
     * Asks the user if they want to save before closing if changes were made.
     */
    private void closePrompt() {
      if(true) {  //board.isDirty()) {
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(main.win, "Save game?");
        if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
          int saved = saveAs();
          if(saved != JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
            main.win.dispose();
          }
        }
        else if(n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
          main.win.dispose();
        }
      }
      else
        main.win.dispose();
    }

  }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: *"I get an error."*  Do you intend to share the error with us, or should we guess?  OK.. for a `TooManyKittensError`, desex the tomcat from next door.

Comment: The object containing the information to be saved is an instance of class `SudokuMain2`? Show us the class...

Comment: I get "Error opening file.", and then subsequently in another dialog box I get: "Incorrect file type."

The SudokuMain2 class is pretty long, and when I tried to include in the initial question, it said I exceeded the character limit for the textbox. Is there something I'm not doing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first portion of the SudokuMain class (I accidentally put "SudokuMain2" instead of "SudokuMain" in MenuAtTop, so ignore the 2):

```
// Allow short name access to following classes
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SudokuMain extends JComponent {

  /**
   * The application method.
   * 
   * @param args The command-line arguments.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SudokuMain();
  }

  // this field refers to the SudokuBase class to access information
  // of the board.
  private SudokuBase board;
  // this field refers to SudokuView object to access its information
  // and provide output
  private SudokuView view;

  // the window all the components are contained in
  private JFrame win;
  // center JPanel object in window
  private JPanel center;
  // left JPanel object in window
  private JPanel west;
  // right JPanel object in window
  private JPanel east;
  // bottom JPanel object in window
  private JPanel south;

  // JPanel object to hold graphic "buttons"
  private JPanel symbols;
  // JPanel object to show "states" of Sudoku board
  private JPanel rowColRegStates;

  // the first set-up window (cannot be changed once
  // instantiated)
  private final Dialog1 setWin1;

  /**
   * Constructs SudokuMain object.
   */
  public SudokuMain() {

    // start game
    board = makeBoard();
    view = new SudokuView(board);

    win = new JFrame("Sudoku Game");
    center = new JPanel();
    west = new JPanel();
    east = new JPanel();
    south = new JPanel();

    // graphic "buttons" for current Sudoku board
    symbols = new SetSymbols(view);
    // "states" of current Sudoku board
    rowColRegStates = new ShowStates(view);

    // the first set-up window
    setWin1 = new Dialog1(this, "New Game", true);

    // create menu bar
    final MenuAtTop menuBar = new MenuAtTop(this);
    win.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    // display game mode
    JLabel mode = new JLabel("Normal Play Mode");
    mode.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    Font modeFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);
    mode.setFont(modeFont);

//    // set selected cell at (0, 0)
//    view.setSelected(0, 0);

    // add window focus listener
    win.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener() {

      public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        win.pack();
        // set selected cell at (0, 0)
        view.setSelected(0, 0);
      }

      public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
      }
    });

    // add window listener
    win.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        menuBar.closePrompt();
      }
    });

    win.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    west.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    east.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    center.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    west.add(symbols);
    east.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    south.add(rowColRegStates);
    center.add(west);
    center.add(east);

    win.add(south, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    win.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    win.add(mode, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    win.pack();
    win.setVisible(true);

  }

  // this inner class constructs graphic "buttons" to set desired
  // cells of board
  class SudokuControlButton extends JPanel {

    // row of selected cell
    private int selRow;
    // column of selected cell
    private int selCol;

    // the value that corresponds with the desired symbol
    private int value;

    /**
     * Constructs SudokuControlButton object; the graphic "button"
     * to control the board.
     * 
     * @param view The SudokuView object to be controlled.
     * @param v The value that corresponds to the desired symbol.
     */
    public SudokuControlButton(final SudokuView view, int v) {
      // set characteristics of graphic "button"
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
      setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

      value = v;

      addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        /**
         * This method selects a "button" and puts it in focus when the mouse
         * is clicked on it.
         * 
         * @param event Captures information on the mouse button being
         *              clicked (pressed and released) on a component.
         */
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          selRow = view.getSelectedRow();
          selCol = view.getSelectedColumn();

          if(!board.isGiven(selRow, selCol)) {
            board.setValue(selRow, selCol, value);
            view.new SudokuCell(selRow, selCol, board);
            // set to "highlighted" color
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            view.repaint();
          }
          else {  // have system beep sound
            getToolkit().beep();
          }

          repaint();
        }

        /**
         * This method handles behavior when the mouse enters a graphic
         * "button".
         * 
         * @param event Captures information on the mouse button being
         *              entered over a component.
         */ 
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
          // set to "highlighted" color
          setBackground(Color.WHITE);

          repaint();
        }

        /**
         * This method handles behavior when the mouse exits a graphic
         * "button".
         * 
         * @param event Captures information on the mouse button being
         *              exited from a component.
         */
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
          // set to default color
          SudokuControlButton button = (SudokuControlButton) e.getSource();

          setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

          repaint();
        }

        /**
         * This method handles behavior when the mouse is pressed on a
         * graphic "button".
         * 
         * @param event Captures information on the mouse button being
         *              pressed on a component.
         */
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
          // set to "active" color
          setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

          repaint();
        }

        /**
         * This method handles behavior when the mouse is released on a
         * graphic "button".
         * 
         * @param e Captures information on the mouse button being
         *              released on a component.
         */
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        }

      });

    }

    /**
     * This method draws the graphic "button" associated with
     * each numeric value, 0 to 12.
     * 
     * @param g The drawing mechanism.
     */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      switch(value) {
        case 0:
          drawSymbol(g, 0);
          break;
        case 1:
          drawSymbol(g, 1);
          break;
        case 2:
          drawSymbol(g, 2);
          break;
        case 3:
          drawSymbol(g, 3);
          break;
        case 4:
          drawSymbol(g, 4);
          break;
        case 5:
          drawSymbol(g, 5);
          break;
        case 6:
          drawSymbol(g, 6);
          break;
        case 7:
          drawSymbol(g, 7);
          break;
        case 8:
          drawSymbol(g, 8);
          break;
        case 9:
          drawSymbol(g, 9);
          break;
        case 10:
          drawSymbol(g, 10);
          break;
        case 11:
          drawSymbol(g, 11);
          break;
        case 12:
          drawSymbol(g, 12);
          break;
      }

    }

    /**
     * This method draws the symbol that corresponds with 
     * the specified value (0-12).
     * 
     * @param g The drawing mechanism.
     * @param value The specified value.
     */
    public void drawSymbol(Graphics g, int value) {

      if(value < 0 || value > 12) {
        String msg = "Value cannot be less than 0 or greater than 12.";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
      }

      // enable drawing with "thick" lines
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));

      switch(value) {
        case 0:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          break;
        case 1:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
          break;
        case 2:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
          g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
          break;
        case 3:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
          g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
          g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 45);
          break;
        case 4:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
          g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
          g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 45);
          g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 45);
          break;
        case 5:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
          g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
          g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 45);
          g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 45);
          g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 45);
          break;
        case 6:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
          g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
          g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 45);
          g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 45);
          g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 45);
          g2.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 45);
          break;
        case 7:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
          g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
          g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
          g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
          g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
          g2.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
          g2.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
          break;
        case 8:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
          g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
          g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
          g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
          g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
          g2.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
          g2.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
          g2.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
          break;
        case 9:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
          g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
          g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
          g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
          g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
          g2.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
          g2.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
          g2.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
          g2.drawLine(15, 30, 15, 45);
          break;
        case 10:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
          g.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
          g.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
          g.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
          g.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
          g.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
          g.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
          g.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
          g.drawLine(15, 30, 15, 45);
          g.drawLine(20, 30, 20, 45);
          break;
        case 11:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
          g.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
          g.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
          g.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
          g.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
          g.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
          g.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
          g.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
          g.drawLine(15, 30, 15, 45);
          g.drawLine(20, 30, 20, 45);
          g.drawLine(25, 30, 25, 45);
          break;
        case 12:
          // draw borders
          g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
          // draw symbol
          g.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
          g.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
          g.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
          g.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
          g.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
          g.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
          g.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
          g.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
          g.drawLine(15, 30, 15, 45);
          g.drawLine(20, 30, 20, 45);
          g.drawLine(25, 30, 25, 45);
          g.drawLine(30, 30, 30, 45);
          break;
      }

    }

  }

  // this inner class provides a JMenuBar object at the top of
  // the board
  class MenuAtTop extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener{

    // SudokuMain object we are dealing with
    private SudokuMain main;

    // the "File" menu
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    // the "New Game" option
    private JMenuItem newGame;
    // the "Open" option
    private JMenuItem open;
    // the "Save" option
    private JMenuItem save;
    // the "Save As" option
    private JMenuItem saveAs;
    // the "Reset" option
    private JMenuItem reset;
    // the "Quit" option
    private JMenuItem quit;

    // the ability to choose files
    private JFileChooser choose;

    // the saved file
//    // compiler would not allow "static" keyword
    private File fileSaved = null;

    private Object opener;

    // JDialog object to create a dialog box to prompt
    // user for new game information
    private JDialog createNewWin; 

    /**
     * Constructs MenuAtTop object.
     * 
     * @param m The SudokuMain object to be referred to.
     */
    public MenuAtTop(final SudokuMain m) {

      main = m;

      opener = null;
      choose = new JFileChooser();

      // instantiate and bind to reference
      fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
      add(fileMenu);

      // instantiate and bind to reference
      newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
      newGame.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,
                                                    ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(newGame);
      newGame.addActionListener(this);

      open = new JMenuItem("Open");
      open.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O,
                                                 ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(open);
      // add action listener to "Open" option
      open.addActionListener(this);

      save = new JMenuItem("Save");
      save.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,
                                                 ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(save);
      // add action listener to "Save" option
      save.addActionListener(this);

      saveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As");
      saveAs.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A,
                                                   ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(saveAs);
      // add action listener to "Save As" option
      saveAs.addActionListener(this);

      reset = new JMenuItem("Reset");
      reset.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R,
                                                  ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(reset);
      // add action listener to "Reset" option
      reset.addActionListener(this);

      quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
      quit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q,
                                                 ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(quit);
      // add action listener to "Quit" option
      quit.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      if(e.getSource().equals(newGame)) {

        setEnabled(false);
        // create dialog box prompting for the new board information
        createNewWin = new Dialog1(main, "Create New Board", true);
        // make it visible
        createNewWin.setVisible(true);

        fileSaved = null;

      } else if(e.getSource().equals(open)) {

        int returnVal = choose.showOpenDialog(main.win);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          boolean error = false;
          File openFile = choose.getSelectedFile();

          try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(openFile);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            opener = ois.readObject();
          } catch (Exception exc) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error opening file.");
            error = true;
          }

          // "opener" reads something and it is of type SudokuBase
          if(opener != null && opener instanceof SudokuBase){
            main.west.remove(main.symbols);
            main.east.remove(main.view);
            main.south.remove(main.rowColRegStates);

            main.view =  new SudokuView((SudokuBase) opener);
            main.symbols = new SetSymbols(main.view);
            main.rowColRegStates = new ShowStates(main.view);

            main.west.add(main.symbols);
            main.east.add(main.view);
            main.south.add(main.rowColRegStates);

            main.win.requestFocus();

            fileSaved = openFile;
          } else {
            if(error) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Incorrect file type.");
            }
          }
        }

      } else if(e.getSource().equals(save)) {

        if(fileSaved == null) {
          saveAsPrompt();
        } else {
          try {
            board.writeToStream(new FileOutputStream(fileSaved));
          } catch (Exception exc) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error saving file.");
          }
        }

      } else if(e.getSource().equals(saveAs)) {
        saveAsPrompt();
      } else if(e.getSource().equals(reset)) {

        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(main.win, 
                                              "Any player values will" +
                                              " be lost. Proceed?",
                                              "Warning!", 2);
        if(n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
          main.board.reset();
          main.view.repaint();
        }

      } else if(e.getSource().equals(quit)) {
        closePrompt();
      }

    }

    // This method prompts the user to choose a file to save to,
    // and then saves the file.
    private int saveAsPrompt() {
      boolean saveError;
      int rtn = choose.showSaveDialog(main.win);

      if(rtn == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        saveError = false;
        File fileSaveAs = choose.getSelectedFile();
        try {
          board.writeToStream(new FileOutputStream(fileSaveAs));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error saving file.");
          saveError = true;
        }

        if(!saveError) {
          fileSaved = fileSaveAs;
        }
      }

      return rtn;

    }

    // This method prompts the user whether they want to save before
    // closing, only if changes occurred.
    private void closePrompt() {
      if(true) {
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(main.win, "Save game?");
        if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
          int saved = saveAsPrompt();
          if(saved != JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
            main.win.dispose();
          }
        } else if(n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
          main.win.dispose();
        }
      }
      else { // no changes were made
        main.win.dispose();
      }
    }

  }
```

...

Answer (score 0):

...   // second and final portion of SudokuMain class

```
  // this inner class provides a dialog box to prompt the user
  // for new board information
  class Dialog1 extends JDialog {

    // rows for new game
    private JTextField rows;
    // cols for new game
    private JTextField cols;
    // button to create a new board
    private JButton createBoard;
    // button to cancel new board and return to
    // previous game
    private JButton cancel;
    // labels for rows per region
    private JLabel rowLabel;
    // label for columns per region
    private JLabel colLabel;
    // label dislayed when error occurs
    private JLabel errorMes;

    // JPanel object to house error message
    private JPanel center;
    // JPanel object to house rows and columns prompt
    private JPanel north;
    // JPanel object to house create new board and cancel buttons
    private JPanel south;
    // JDialog object to create window for new game
    private JDialog createWin2;

    /**
     * Constructs Dialog1 object.
     * 
     * @param win The window containing the dialog box.
     * @param header The title of the dialog box.
     * @param modal Whether dialog box is modal or not.
     */
    public Dialog1(final SudokuMain win, String header, boolean modal) {
      // call superclass constructor
      super();

      // instantiate and bind to references
      rows = new JTextField(2);
      cols = new JTextField(2);
      createBoard = new JButton("Create New Board");
      cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
      rowLabel = new JLabel("Rows per region: ");
      colLabel = new JLabel("Columns per region: ");
      errorMes = new JLabel();

      north = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      center = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      south = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

      // set characteristics
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      setTitle(header);
      setModal(modal);
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      // set characteristics of error message
      errorMes.setForeground(Color.RED);
      errorMes.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 12));
      errorMes.setVisible(false);

      // keep track of "old" board
      final SudokuBase oldBoard = board;

      // add action listener for "Cancel" button
      cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        /**
         * This method handles the action of activating the
         * "Cancel" button to make the dialog box "invisible".
         * 
         * @param e Captures information about the event that occurred.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          setVisible(false);
        }
      });

      // add action listener for "Create Board" button
      createBoard.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        /**
         * This method handles the action of activating the
         * "Cancel" button to make the dialog box "invisible".
         * 
         * @param e Captures information about the event that occurred.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          int newRows;
          int newCols;
          int newSize;

          // handles potential exception when converting String input
          // to int
          try{
            newRows = Integer.parseInt(rows.getText());
            newCols = Integer.parseInt(cols.getText());
          } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            newRows = 0;
            newCols = 0;
          }

          newSize = newRows * newCols;
          // input validation
          if(newSize <= 0 || newSize > 12) {
            errorMes.setText("Rows times columns cannot be less than one" +
                             " or greater than 12!");
            errorMes.setVisible(true);
            pack();

          } else {
            errorMes.setVisible(false);
            setVisible(false);

            // update board to new board
            board = new SudokuBoard(newRows, newCols);
            createWin2 = new Dialog2(win, oldBoard, view, symbols, newRows,
                                     newCols, "New Sudoku Game", true);
          }
        }});


      // place error message in the center
      center.add(errorMes);

      // place labels for rows and columns at the top 
      north.add(rowLabel);
      north.add(rows);
      north.add(colLabel);
      north.add(cols);
      // place both buttons at bottom
      south.add(createBoard);
      south.add(cancel);

      add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      pack();

      if(!win.win.isVisible()) {
        dispose();
      }

    }
  }

  // this inner class a dialog box to house a new game
  class Dialog2 extends JDialog {

    // view to be used
    private SudokuView view;

    // the panel to house the board (view) and both the
    // "Set givens" and "Cancel" buttons
    private JPanel panel;
    // panel placed within "panel" that houses both the "Set givens"
    // and "Cancel" buttons
    private JPanel northPanel;
    // panel to house the graphic "buttons"
    private JPanel symbols;

    // "Set givens" button
    private JButton setGivenCells;
    // "Cancel" button
    private JButton cancel;

    /**
     * Constructs Dialog2 object.
     * 
     * @param win The window containing the dialog box.
     * @param oldBoard The "old" SudokuBoard to keep track of.
     * @param oldView The "old" SudokuView to keep track of.
     * @param oldSymbols The "old" graphic "buttons" to keep track of.
     * @param rows The rows of the new Sudoku board to be created.
     * @param cols The columns of the new Sudoku board to be created.
     * @param header The title of the dialog box.
     * @param modal Whether the dialog box is modal or not.
     */
    public Dialog2(final SudokuMain mainWin, final SudokuBase oldBoard,
                   final SudokuView oldView, final JPanel oldSymbols,
                   int rows, int cols, String header, boolean modal) {
      // call superclass constructor
      super();

      // instantiate and bind to references
      view = new SudokuView(board);
      panel = new JPanel();
      northPanel = new JPanel();
      setGivenCells = new JButton("Set givens");
      cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
      symbols = new SetSymbols(view);

      // create menu bar
      final MenuAtTop menuBar = new MenuAtTop(mainWin);
      setJMenuBar(menuBar);

      // display "Set-Up Mode"
      final JLabel setupMode = new JLabel("Set-Up Mode");
      setupMode.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      Font setupModeFont = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18);
      setupMode.setFont(setupModeFont);
      setupMode.setForeground(Color.RED);

      // display "Normal Play Mode"
      final JLabel mode = new JLabel("Normal Play Mode");
      mode.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      Font modeFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);
      mode.setFont(modeFont);

      // set up characteristics
      setTitle(header);
      setModal(modal);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      // add action listener to "Set givens" button
      setGivenCells.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        /**
         * This method handles the action of activating the
         * "Set givens" button.
         * 
         * @param e Captures information about the event that occurred.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          // set "given" cells
          board.fixGivens();

//          // have window refer to new board
//          mainWin.west.remove(mainWin.symbols);
//          mainWin.east.remove(mainWin.view);
//          
//          mainWin.view = view;
//          mainWin.symbols = symbols;
//          
//          mainWin.west.add(mainWin.symbols);
//          mainWin.east.add(mainWin.view);

          // remove "Set-Up Mode" label and replace with
          // "Normal Play Mode" label
          panel.remove(setupMode);
          panel.add(mode, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

          // disable both buttons
          setGivenCells.setEnabled(false);
          cancel.setEnabled(false);

          validate();
          repaint();

        }
      });

      // add action listener to "Cancel" button
      cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        /**
         * This method handles the action of activating the
         * "Cancel" button.
         * 
         * @param e Captures information about the event that occurred.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          // have window refer to "old" board
          board = oldBoard;

          mainWin.west.remove(mainWin.symbols);
          mainWin.east.remove(mainWin.view);

          mainWin.view = oldView;
          mainWin.symbols = oldSymbols;

          mainWin.west.add(mainWin.symbols);
          mainWin.east.add(mainWin.view);

          // disable both buttons
          setGivenCells.setEnabled(false);
          cancel.setEnabled(false);

          setVisible(false);

          repaint();

        }
      });

      // place buttons at the top
      northPanel.add(setGivenCells);
      northPanel.add(cancel);

      // place board to fill remainder of space not
      // occupied by buttons at the top
      panel.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      panel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      panel.add(setupMode, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      // place graphic "buttons" to left of board
      add(symbols);
      add(panel);

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
      setVisible(true);

    }

  }



// this inner class creates the graphic "buttons" to set the selected cell
  // to the desired "button"
  class SetSymbols extends JPanel {

    // temporary board provides information to create graphic "buttons"
    private SudokuBoard tempBd;

    private int value;

    /**
     * Constructs SetSymbols object.
     * 
     * @param view The SudokuView object for SetSymbols.
     */
    public SetSymbols(final SudokuView view) {
      // instantiate and bind to reference
      tempBd = new SudokuBoard(1, board.getBoardSize() + 1);

      setLayout(new GridLayout((tempBd.getBoardSize())/2 + 1, 2));

      for(int colSymbol = 0; colSymbol < tempBd.getBoardSize(); colSymbol++) {
        // keep track of value of graphic "button"
        value = colSymbol;

        final JPanel symPanel = new JPanel();

        // set value for each graphic "button"
        tempBd.setValue(0, colSymbol, colSymbol);
        // add the appropriate symbol to each graphic "button"
        symPanel.add(new SudokuControlButton(view, value));

        // add graphic "button"
        add(symPanel);

      }

    }

    /**
     * Draws the symbol associated with each
     * numeric value (0 to 12) on the non-given
     * selected cell.
     * 
     * @param g The drawing mechanism.
     */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      // get selected cell information from SudokuView reference
      int row = view.getSelectedRow();
      int col = view.getSelectedColumn();

      switch(value) {
        case 0:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 1:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 2:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 3:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 4:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 5:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 6:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 7:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 8:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 9:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 10:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 11:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
        case 12:
          view.new SudokuCell(row, col, board).drawSymbol(g, row, col);
          break;
      }

    }

  }

  // this inner class displays the state information for each row, column, and region
  class ShowStates extends JPanel{

    // the SudokuView object to be used
    private SudokuView view;

    // JPanel for row state
    private JPanel rowSt;
    // JPanel for column state
    private JPanel columnSt;
    // JPanel for region state
    private JPanel regionSt;
    // displays row state
    private JPanel[] rowStColor;
    // displays column state
    private JPanel[] columnStColor;
    // displays region state
    private JPanel[] regionStColor;

    // number of rows per region
    private int rows;
    // number of columns per region
    private int columns;
    // size per region (rows * columns)
    private int size;

    /**
     * Constructs the ShowStates object.
     *
     * @param view The SudokuView object for ShowStates. 
     */
    public ShowStates(SudokuView v) {

      // bind to references
      rows = board.getRowsPerRegion();
      columns = board.getColumnsPerRegion();
      size = rows * columns;

      // bind to reference
      view = v;

      // row characteristics
      rowSt = new JPanel();
      rowSt.setLayout(new GridLayout(size, 1));
      rowStColor = new JPanel[size];
      rowSt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
      rowSt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

      // column characteristics
      columnSt = new JPanel();
      columnSt.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, size));
      columnStColor = new JPanel[size];
      columnSt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
      columnSt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

      // region characteristics
      regionSt = new JPanel();
      regionSt.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, columns));
      regionStColor = new JPanel[size];
      regionSt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
      regionSt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // instantiate and bind to references
        JPanel rowPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel columnPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel regionPanel = new JPanel();

        rowStColor[i] = rowPanel;
        columnStColor[i] = columnPanel;
        regionStColor[i] = regionPanel;

        // add to respective JPanel objects
        rowSt.add(rowPanel);
        columnSt.add(columnPanel);
        regionSt.add(regionPanel);
      }

      // add each state to "this" JPanel
      add(rowSt);
      add(columnSt);
      add(regionSt);

    }

    /**
     * This method draws the appropriate color to display the state information.
     * 
     * @param g The drawing mechanism.
     */
    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      for(int i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++) {

        // check the state of each row
        if(board.getRowState(i) == SudokuBase.State.ERROR){
          rowStColor[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        else if(board.getRowState(i) == SudokuBase.State.INCOMPLETE) {
          rowStColor[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        else { // board.getRowState(i) == SudokuBase.State.COMPLETE
          rowStColor[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        // check the state of each column
        if(board.getColumnState(i) == SudokuBase.State.ERROR){
          columnStColor[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        else if(board.getColumnState(i) == SudokuBase.State.INCOMPLETE) {
          columnStColor[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        else { // board.getColumnState(i) == SudokuBase.State.COMPLETE
          columnStColor[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        // check the state of each region
        if(board.getRegionState(i) == SudokuBase.State.ERROR){
          regionStColor[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        else if(board.getRegionState(i) == SudokuBase.State.INCOMPLETE) {
          regionStColor[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        else { // board.getRegionState(i) == SudokuBase.State.COMPLETE
          regionStColor[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

      }

    }

  }

  /**
   * This method provides a pre-set board to start with in
   * "Normal Play" mode.
   * 
   * @return The board with the "givens" already set.
   */
  public static SudokuBase makeBoard() {
    SudokuBase board = new SudokuBoard(2, 3);
    board.setValue(0, 3, 6);
    board.setValue(0, 5, 1);
    board.setValue(1, 2, 4);
    board.setValue(1, 4, 5);
    board.setValue(1, 5, 3);
    board.setValue(2, 3, 3);
    board.setValue(3, 2, 6);
    board.setValue(4, 0, 2);
    board.setValue(4, 1, 3);
    board.setValue(4, 3, 1);
    board.setValue(5, 0, 6);
    board.setValue(5, 2, 1);
    board.fixGivens();

    return board;
  }

}
```

Comment: Here is the SudokuMain class in 2 installments. I know they are not answers, but I did not know how else to post my huge class.